# Polymer 1.0 DEEP path observation (multiple levels)

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, observers

I have an issue wherein I need to observe DEEP changes to a JSON object.  For example the object could look something like the ***proj*** object shown below.  The ***specs*** sub-property is referenceable (should always exist).  However, all the deeper sub-properties in all of the various levels below ***specs*** are not necessarily named anything defined (each level is a dictionary of unknown types).  Despite this, I need to know when any deep sub-property value of ***specs*** changes, or any new subproperties are added, even down to lowest level (3 levels down from specs in this case).

```
{proj: 
        { id: "foo",
          specs: { 
             specA: {0: { 
                          width: 1.01, 
                          height: 2.0
                        }, 
                     1: { width: 2.50 } 
                     2: { depth: 3.00 }
                    }, 
             specB: {1, 5, 10}, 
             specC: {3, 4, 5, 6} } 
             } 
        }
}
```

I've tried using polymer's suggested deep path observation technique, using the path wildcard (*):

```
observers: [ '_specsChanged(proj.specs.*)' ]
```

However, this method seems to only watch for changes one level below specs.  How do I watch for changes at ANY level below specs with a single observer declaration?

Answer (score 1):

Could you post an example showing your problem? [Here's an example where path observation works.](http://jsfiddle.net/9qd42Lq3/) Your observers array is fine:

```
observers: ['_specsChanged(proj.specs.*)'],
```

Deep path observation should work at any level, but only if the property is changing via data binding or Polymer methods like [set](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#set-path) or the [array functions](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html#array-observation).

Comment: I am indeed using Polymer's set method on proj.specs.  If I do this:  `this.set('proj.specs', detail.newSpecs); `, which in effect alters values two levels further down (i.e. a width or depth value in example above), or adds  subproperties in levels deeper, the path observer doesn't fire.  Should it?